# How to use actor inside of spray route in REST service?

Tags: scala, rest, akka, spray

I'm trying to build event sourced service with REST interface using scala. I somewhat new to scala, although I'm familiar with functional programming (haskell at beginner level).

So I've build persistent actor and view without major problems. The idea of actors is quite simple I think.

```
object Main extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("HelloSystem")
  val systemActor = system.actorOf(Props[SystemActor], name = "systemactor")
  val trajectoryView = system.actorOf(Props[TrajectoryView], name = "trajectoryView")
  var datas = List()
  val processData = ProcessData(0, List(1,2,3), Coordinates(50, 50))

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
  def intialDatas(): List[ProcessData] =
    (for (i <- 1 to 3) yield ProcessData(i, List(1,2,3), Coordinates(50 + i, 50 + i)))(collection.breakOut)
  val command = RegisterProcessCommand(3, this.intialDatas())
  val id = Await.result(systemActor ? command, timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[String]
  println(id)
  systemActor ! MoveProcessCommand(4, ProcessData(4, List(3,4,5), Coordinates(54, 54)), id)

  val processes = Await.result(systemActor ? "get", timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[Set[Process]]
  println(processes)
  implicit val json4sFormats = DefaultFormats
  println(write(processes))
  println("*****************")
  systemActor ! "print"
  val getTrajectoryCommand = GetTrajectoryCommand(id)
  Thread.sleep(10000)
  trajectoryView ! "print"
//  val trajectory = Await.result(trajectoryView ? getTrajectoryCommand, timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[ListBuffer[Coordinates]]
  println("******* TRAJECTORY *********")
  trajectoryView ! "print"
//  println(trajectory)

  system.shutdown()
}
```

I've been able to create a script for playing with actor that I've created.

I've read the tutorials for spray routing, but I've been unable to grasp what exactly should I do to provide REST interface for actors that I've created.

```
object Boot extends App{
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("example")
  val systemActor = system.actorOf(Props[SystemActor], name = "systemactor")
  val trajectoryView = system.actorOf(Props[TrajectoryView], name = "trajectoryView")


  val service = system.actorOf(Props[ProcessesService], "processes-rest-service")

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
  IO(Http) ? Http.Bind(service, interface = "localhost", port = 8080)
}
```

And a service

```
class ProcessesService(systemActor: ActorRef) extends Actor with HttpService {


  def actorRefFactory = context
  def receive = runRoute(route)

  val json4sFormats = DefaultFormats

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
  val route = path("processes") {
    get {
      respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) {
        complete {
          write(Await.result(systemActor ? "get", timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[Set[Process]])
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I think I need to somehow pass actorRef for SystemActor to this ProcessesService, but I'm not sure how. Also I'm not sure how should I return a response to the request. I understand that I need to somehow pass the "get" message to SystemActor through ActorRef and then serialize the answer to json, but I don't know how to do that.

I would appreciate help!

Answer (score 0):

In spray you can complete routes with a `Future`.

You should be able to do something like

```
complete { systemActor ? "get" }
```

Json serialization is a separate issue.

Oh, your question is vague. Yes you need to be able to reference an actor within your routes. You could just import the val from `boot` where you define it. They're just Scala variables so where you put them is up to you.

Comment: Well, it's separate, but my question is about both of them. I've already found about complete with a future (it's easy to google). It would be helpful if you could provide some simple fully working example (with serialization).

Comment: You found the Boot part from the spray example.  Working with actors is separate from getting a spray routing app working.  It sounds like you might want to focus on getting a simple spray app working first. Once you get that working you can worry about plugging in the actors.

Comment: I've got a fairly basic spray app example here https://github.com/corndog/whereis